# Is eye colour of Drosophila a polygenic trait or an X-linked trait?

Tags: genetics

I have seen examples of various eye colours in *Drosophila* and they have been described both as "X-linked" and "polygenic". I thought these were mutually exclusive. Is *Drosophila* eye colour polygenic or X-linked?

Comment: A trait can be X-linked and polygenic. It is not contradictory. Can you please link to your references?

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear, the user didn't understand the terms X-linked and polygenic properly. I have voted for reopening. @SanjuktaGhosh could you add sources to this showing where it says they are x-linked/polygenic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Polygenic and X-linked are not mutually exclusive**; a trait can be polygenic, X-linked, neither, or both.

**Polygenic traits are those affected by many genes.** According to Conner and Hartl, *"Traits that are affected by many gene loci are often called polygenic traits."* For example, [childhood intelligence is affected by many genes](http://www.nature.com/mp/journal/v19/n2/full/mp2012184a.html) throughout the genome. Monogenic traits are relatively rare, but are [linked to some diseases](http://www.who.int/genomics/public/geneticdiseases/en/index2.html), and occur when a single gene affects the trait; most traits are affected by multiple genes.

**X-linked traits are affected by genes (only) situated on the X.** If a trait is monogenic, it is very easy to describe it as being, or not being, X-linked. [If the gene is on the X, it is X-linked. If it is on the Y, it is Y-linked.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_linkage) If it is in the autosomes, it is autosomally linked. If all of the genes affecting a trait are found on the X then that *trait* is X-linked. A gene on the X is X-linked, but *I* would only call a *trait* X-linked if all genes were on the X. If there was a mix of X-linked and autosomal genetic variation I would describe the trait as having some X-linked genes.

**For polygenic traits it is less likely that the genes would be *all* X-linked**, so it is less likely that the *trait* is X-linked. Imagine a trait affected by 10 genes, and those 10 genes are randomly spread across the genome. It is unlikely that all 10 would be on the X. However, if some were on the X, then we could describe the trait as having X-linked variation. Many highly polygenic traits will have some X-linked variation.

Having more genes affecting the trait further increases the probability that some genes will be on the sex chromosomes. For example, lifespan is expected to be a highly polygenic trait, and [genetic variation in lifepsan can be attributed to the Y chromosome](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jeb.12708/abstract) in *Drosophila melanogaster*, despite the Y carrying just a tiny fraction of the genes.

Many eye colour traits in *Drosophila* can be attributed to single genes, and *White* in the [image below](https://www.mun.ca/biology/scarr/Drosophila_eye_colors.html) is X-linked. However, one can also produce a white-eyed fly using multiple genes; in [this paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/102/suppl_1/6527.full) one of the lines used has white eyes as a result of combining genes (T(2;3) rdg<sup>C</sup> st p<sup>p</sup> bw<sup>D</sup>) which are on the autosomes.

[image]